# Resolving Dialog Fragment memory leak with LeakCanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-dialogfragment, leakcanary

I have a listview with textview in each item which when clicked launches a dialog with a numberpicker elements to change the values in the item. When checking for memory leaks with LeakCanary library, I have come across this memory leak associated with the dialog fragments which shows up when I repeatedly launch and dismiss the dialogs. I have also looked at similar posts on Stack Overflow, but none have helped to solve the issue. Implementation of dialog fragment is as below:

```
public class NumberDialog extends DialogFragment {
        NumberPicker numberPicker;
        NumberPicker numberPicker2;
        NumberPicker numberPicker3;
        public static NumberDialog newInstance() {
            NumberDialog frag = new NumberDialog ();
            return frag;
        }


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View child = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
             numberPicker = child.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
              numberPicker2 = child.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
               numberPicker3 = child.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);

            numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
            numberPicker3.setMinValue(0);
            numberPicker3.setMaxValue(59);

            numberPicker2.setMinValue(0);
            numberPicker2.setMaxValue(59);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);


            builder.setTitle("Choose Value");


            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dismiss();

                }
            });

            builder.setView(child);
            return builder.create();
        }




    }
```

The screenshot for the leak source is below:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsunw.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4ACk.jpg)